# Side effects of ivermectin and anti-hypertensive drugs

Tags: medications, side-effects, hypertension

Are there any side effects when the drug Ivermectin and anti-hypertensive drugs are taken together? I'm only asking out of curiosity. I worked briefly as an intern with US-AIDS for the control and eradication of onchocerciasis in West Africa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ivermectin (Stromectol) is a broad-spectrum antiparasitic agent with macrocyclic lactones structure, Ivermectin acts by interfering with **nervous system** and muscle function,in particular by **Binding GluCls ion channels** [(1)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23038250) in invertebrate nerve and muscle cells,produces paralysis, death of parasite.[(2)](http://reference.medscape.com/drug/stromectol-ivermectin-342657#10)

Medications that interfere with **P-glycoprotein**( multidrug resistance protein 1 (MDR1)) have the potential to effect on systemic/CNS exposure of Ivermectin and its elimination.[(3)](http://www.ejcancer.com/article/0959-8049(96)00063-9/abstract)[,(4)](http://www.fda.gov/Drugs/DevelopmentApprovalProcess/DevelopmentResources/DrugInteractionsLabeling/ucm093664.htm)[,(5)](http://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/841642_4)

**hypertension drugs** like verapamil,reserpine,diltiazem and etc plus other Heart Disease medications like amiodarone and warfarin can interfere with above mechanism , its important to say **this interaction not known as contraindication or serious interactions
but categorized as Significant interactions which needs close monitoring** so there is no need for drug alternation unless you see significant side effects in the patient .[(6)](http://www.rxlist.com/drug-interactions/serious-index/ivermectin-oral.htm),[(7)](http://reference.medscape.com/drug/stromectol-ivermectin-342657#3)

Drugs that have serious interaction with Ivermectin are ivacaftor
and quinidine ( in every form and combination).[(6)](http://www.rxlist.com/drug-interactions/serious-index/ivermectin-oral.htm),[(7)](http://reference.medscape.com/drug/stromectol-ivermectin-342657#3)

To see complete Interaction list checkout 
[Medscape](http://reference.medscape.com/drug/stromectol-ivermectin-342657#3) and [Rxlist](http://www.rxlist.com/drug-interactions/serious-index/ivermectin-oral.htm)